# BeautifulSoup4 Python3 gives wrong values from referenced table

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to get the table appearing in https://covid19.isciii.es/ using bs4 + Python3.

[image: table to be extracted]

When I inspect the values with my browser, the website shows up the same values

[image: inspect table]

But the code shows me up different values [i.e., (71,0,0) for Andalucia instead of the current one (4682,405,50.45) ]

```
url_base = 'https://covid19.isciii.es/'
response = get(url_base)
print(response)
if response.status_code == 200:
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(get(url_base).text, 'html.parser').findAll("td")
    print(html_soup)
```

[image: execution result]

Why is this happening? How can I solve this with bs4?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `response.content`?

Comment: The value is correct, 200, so it get all the information successfully, but the values seem to be different from the appearing ones.

Comment: The reason for the problem is when you inspect the payload from `https://covid19.isciii.es/` in the network tab, there the data is `(71,0,0) for Andalucia`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this in 2 rows:=

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://covid19.isciii.es/")[0]
```

XHR actually gives me a different URL which has the correct value:-

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://covid19.isciii.es/resources/ccaa.csv")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem is that the values are still different from the ones shown in the table. As you can see, in your result Andalucia is showing (71,0,0) and these are not the ones from the website.

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left-hand side in my answer. And feel free to upvote the answer.